# Python selenium - import class

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver, import

I'm trying to put my locators to other file and import it in test case. Unfortunately when i try to run the test it throws an error about Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. When i don't use import but use just driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']") it works fine. The attempt is carried out on "cookie_button".

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from footer_locators import locators


service = Service("C:\\Users\\Hubert\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)


class TestScenario_footer(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        driver.quit()

    def test_TC01_check_facebook(self):
        locators.cookie_button.click()
        main_page = driver.current_window_handle
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[normalize-space()='Facebook']").click()
        for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
            if window_handle != main_page:
                driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        print(driver.current_url)
        assert driver.current_url == "https://www.facebook.com/otomotopl"
```

footer_locators:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service("C:\\Users\\Hubert\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)


class locators:
    cookie_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
```

Comment: there is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - `class Locators` - because it helps to recognize class in code. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: don't create `driver` in separated file `footer_locators` because code will use different instance of driver without running `get(url)`. Create it only in main file and send it as parameter to class `locator` - and this may need to use `__init__` to set `self.driver` in class or use functions in class - to get `driver` as parameter. (PL: nie twórz `driver` w `footer_locators` bo to tworzy nowy object, który nie wykonuje `get(url)`. Powinieneś stworzyć `driver` tylko w głownym pliku i wysłac jako parametr do `locator` ale to wymaga funkcji, które biorą driver jak parameter)

Answer (score 1):

You may have two problems

- you create separated `driver` in `footer_locators`
- you create `cookie_button` in class in wrong way.

When you import `footer_locators` then it creates `driver` and it runs at once `driver.find_xpath()` to assign result to `cookie_button`. So to doesn't run `.get()` to load page (because you run it later in main file using different instance). And it will NOT assign function to `cookie_button` to execute it later but result from `find_xpath()`. It needs to create normal function or `lambda` function

You should also create `driver` only in main file and send it as parameter to function in class or to instance of class (`__init__`) to use it as `self.driver`

BTW: There is good rule to use `CamelCaseNames` for classes - class Locators` - because it helps to recognize class in code. You can see it in second method.

---

First method - as static class

```
class Locators:
    
    @staticmethod
    def cookie_button(driver):
        return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
```

and later

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")

Locators.cookie_button(driver).click()
```

---

Second method - as instance

```
class Locators:
    
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver 

    def cookie_button(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
```

and later

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")

locators = Locators(driver)      # create instance

locators.cookie_button().click()
```

In this version you can also use `@property` to run `cookie_button` without `()`

```
class Locators:
    
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver 

    @property
    def cookie_button(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
```

and later

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")

locators = Locators(driver)      # create instance

locators.cookie_button.click()   # `cookie_button` without `()`
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests.

```
# === Version 1 ===

# --- module ---

class Locators:
    
    def cookie_button(driver):
        print('url:', driver.current_url)
        return driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
    
# - main file -

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Locators.cookie_button(driver).click()

driver.close()

# === Version 2 ===

# --- module ---

class Locators:
    
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver 

    @property
    def cookie_button(self):
        print('url:', driver.current_url)
        return self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")
    
# --- main file ---

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.otomoto.pl/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

locators = Locators(driver)

locators.cookie_button.click()

driver.close()
```